# Function to discord minimum value from a vector not working

Tags: r, function, rstudio

I am trying to create a function that orders the sample of observations and then discards the minimum value. Then, to compute the mean of the remaining observations.

I am having issues with the function. This is what I was trying to do:

```
Deletion1 <- function(z){
  sortz <- sort(z)
  answer <- sum(sortz[sortz!=min(sortz)])/length(z)-1)
  return(answer)
}
```

The error I get is that I have an unexpected } and ). I am trying to understand which ones are wrong and why, but I don't see them? They seem okay to me, and I have played around them and nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In the third line, some parentheses doesn't have an opening `(`

```
sum(sortz[sortz!=min(sortz)])/length(x)-1)
                               ^
```

should be

```
sum(sortz[sortz!=min(sortz)])/(length(x)-1)
```

Or if the `sum` should be done on the divided value

```
sum(sortz[sortz!=min(sortz)]/(length(x)-1))
```